# Keeping tracks of elements in a list in scala

Tags: list, scala

Suppose you are given the following list: {1,0,0,3,4,0,8,0,5,6,0}. Is there any way I can assign a particular index to all the 0s in the list in SCALA? This index must then be used as a parameter to another function.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, an example output of this hypothetical function would help.

Comment: I and at least one other user figured out what you may have meant. I'm not sure that downvoting is an efficient mode of arriving at clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure what you mean, but perhaps this will give you some ideas:

```
scala> val list = List(3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2)
list: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2)

scala> val indexed = list.zipWithIndex
indexed: List[(Int, Int)] = List((3,0), (4,1), (0,2), (0,3), (3,4), (0,5), (2,6))

scala> val zeroIndices = indexed collect { case (value, index) if value == 0 => index }
zeroIndices: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 5)
```

Bonus:

```
scala> zeroIndices map list
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Hey, the OP is asking about `{1,0,0,3,4,0,8,0,5,6,0}`, but your example is `List(3, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 2)`, which is like a totally different list, except for `3,4,0`. But +1 for the hilarious bonus.  Seriously, as a beginner it's easy to miss the utility of `zipWithIndex`.

Comment: Vectors are optimized for random access using indexes. You might consider using one if that is all you are doing with the collection. Lists are optimized for recursive functions traversing a list.